# PHP not printing special characters

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm receiving a text file upload and then just printing it back out.  For some reason, special characters are appearing as black boxes with a white check mark.  I tried htmlentities() and utf8_encode() on the content to be print to screen, but that didn't help.

Here's all of my code:

```
<?php ini_set("auto_detect_line_endings", true);
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>
<body style="overflow:visible;">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file" />
<button type="submit" name="upload" value="upload">Upload</button>
</form>
<pre>
<?php

if($_POST['upload']) {
//$fileName = 'old.txt';
$fileName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];


    if(file_exists($fileName)) {
        $file = fopen($fileName,'r');
        while(!feof($file)) {
            $name = fgets($file);
            echo(htmlentities($name));
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
}
?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

This code works on my localhost LAMP server, but the character probelm appears on some other people's servers.  What can I do to maek the special characters show up?

Comment: Is the uploaded file actually UTF-8? Unicode is not some magic way of fixing enconding errors. It is just yet-another-character-encoding.

Comment: @BartFriederichs - how can I tell?  I tried a mb_detect_encoding($name, 'auto', true) but that returned nothing/false.

Comment: I'd use `file`, it will include an `exec` call, but it is your best best on getting an accurate MIME. http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?file